# Using a multi tap transformer

Tags: power-supply, ac, transformer

I'm new to electronics I have need some help with a power supply design I am designing.

I currently have a 0-30 volt, 2 amp multi tap transformer that I am using for the above mentioned power supply but what I am wanting to know whether is I can set it up so that I can tap more than one voltage at a time ( not simultaneously but to be able to flick between one and another )  and if so would I have to set a separate rectifier for each circuit for a given voltage.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a switch to select different taps, and as long as your rectifier/filter circuit is designed for the voltage while on the highest tap and the maximum current while on the lowest tap, you only need one rectifier/filter circuit after the tap selector switch.

Your best selection for a switch to use is a "Break-Before-Make" switch.